# Lumia 1020 headphones functionality?

Tags: settings, nokia-lumia-1020, audio

Can someone tell me functionalities of Nokia Lumia 1020 headphones do?

I was wondering, how to control volume using lumia 1020 headphones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no volume control on the headphones, so it is just as simple as using the volume control on the phone, at the top right.